# Oracle AWS RDS conditional Compilation

Tags: oracle, plsql, amazon-rds, oracle12c, conditional-compilation

I'm porting my oracle DB to AWS RDS. And I need to implement some new packages if it's only RDS. So how do I do the conditional compilation in RDS? Is there a package like `DBMS_DB_VERSION` which has constants so that I can identify if it's an RDS instance or not?

Answer (score 1):

See the article in "[Obsessed with Oracle PL/SQL"](https://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2019/03/an-introduction-to-conditional.html) on Conditional compilation. It, along with the included links, does a pretty good job covering the topic at least from Oracle's perspective.

> Conditional compilation allows the compiler to compile selected parts
> of a program based on conditions you specify using $ syntax in PL/SQL.
> When you see statements like $IF, $ELSE, $END and $ERROR in your
> PL/SQL code, you are looking at conditional compilations, sometimes
> also referred to as "ifdef" processing. ...

There is no Oracle supplied DBMS package telling if it is a AWS RDS. You would have to consult your AWS Documentation. Perhaps you can determine that from the connection information otherwise.